# Quarkus mysql UTF8 hibernate cannot insert utf8 characters

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, encoding, quarkus-panache

When I insert data with special characters with liquibase from SQL file it works.
When I insert data with special characters from IntelliJ console via SQL insert it works.
When I insert data with special characters by persisting an entity it gives the following
error:

```
(Quarkus Main Thread) Incorrect string value: '\xE1\xE1\xE1\xE1\xE1\xE1...' for column 'LEGAL_CLASSIFICATION' at row 1
```

The data I would like to insert:

```
            product.setLegalClassification("ááááááásdaásdáasáá");
            product.persist();
```

Properties:

```
  hibernate-orm:
    dialect: "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"
  datasource:
    db-kind: mysql
    username: ${DB_USER}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    jdbc:
      driver: "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
      url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my-db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8"
```

I've already tried with URLs:

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my-db?characterEncoding=utf8"
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my-db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my-db?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my-db?useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf8;"
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my-db?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=utf8"
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my-db?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my-db?useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8;"
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my-db?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

and driver:

```
"org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"
"org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"
```

The column type is set like this:

```
<column name="LEGAL_CLASSIFICATION"
                    type="LONGTEXT"/>

and in a MySQL dbms SQL changeset:

ALTER TABLE PRODUCT MODIFY COLUMN LEGAL_CLASSIFICATION LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_hungarian_ci;
```

I tried to query database info with the following results:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME 'database', default_character_set_name 'charset', DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME 'collation' FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA;
gives
    database,   charset,    collation
    information_schema, utf8mb3,    utf8_general_ci
    my-db,  utf8mb4,    utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci


show variables like 'character%';
gives
    variable_name,  value
    character_set_client,   utf8mb4
    character_set_connection,   utf8mb4
    character_set_database, utf8mb4
    character_set_filesystem,   binary
    character_set_results,  utf8mb4
    character_set_server,   utf8mb4
    character_set_system,   utf8mb3
    character_sets_dir, /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/


show variables like 'collation%';
gives
    variable_name,  value
    collation_connection,   utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    collation_database, utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
    collation_server,   utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

SELECT DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME, DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA S WHERE schema_name = 'my-db';
gives
    default_character_set_name, default_collation_name
    utf8mb4,    utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Before I set the collation and character set on the columns I could not even insert data from SQL file via liquibase but altering tables fixed it, although I still can't insert through hibernate...

Does anybody have an idea what I should do to make it work?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

**UPDATE (solution/workaround)!!**

I've found out that even without jdbc url parameters varchar and longvarbinary columns are working correctly from SQL file, terminal and even through hibernate.

So the only column that's not encoded correctly is the one with LONGTEXT. Unfortunately for me varchar is too short for the job, so currently I solved this issue by using type="JAVA.SQL.TYPES.LONGVARBINARY" as column type (with this I don't even need the column alteration) and I put @Lob on a byte[] entity field and convert the data while I'm mapping the field to a dto.

My Entity:

```
    @Column(name = "LEGAL_CLASSIFICATION")
    @Lob
    private byte[] legalClassification;
```

Liquibase column:

```
            <column name="LEGAL_CLASSIFICATION"
                    type="JAVA.SQL.TYPES.LONGVARBINARY"/>
```

Mapping:

```
    @Mapping(source = "legalClassification", target = "legalClassification", qualifiedByName = "toUtf8")
    ProductModel toModel(Product entity);

    @Mapping(source = "legalClassification", target = "legalClassification", qualifiedByName = "fromUtf8")
    Product toEntity(ProductModel entity);

    @Named("toUtf8")
    default String toUtf8(byte[] entity) {
        return entity == null ? null : new String(entity, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    @Named("fromUtf8")
    default byte[] fromUtf8(String model) {
        return model == null ? null : model.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
```

Now Everything is working fine, with good 4byte utf8 encoding. Altough I did not find any documentation how this works in MySQL or hibernate and why I cannot store 4byte utf8 encoded strings in TEXT and LONGTEXT type columns. I would appreciate an explanation on that.

Comment: Show us the text that turned into E1E1E1...

Comment: I mentioned it in the original post:
The data I would like to insert:

            product.setLegalClassification("ááááááásdaásdáasáá");
            product.persist();
The character á will be \xE1

Comment: I think recent driver versions started messing with the way the character set is determined through JDBC. Inserts through liqiubase and the console work because you are not really using parameter markers. These tools just inline the values as literals. If you use parameter markers though, the driver will make use of the configured/inferred character set and problems will start popping up. Try using `?characterEncoding=utf8mb4&connectionCollation=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`

Comment: @ViktorKorai - Does `ááááááásdaásdáasáá` look reasonable?  If not back up to where that comes from.  This is not a typical way for strings to be garbled; I am hoping to find the source.

Comment: @RickJames Yeah I just use it for testing this is hard coded in my code currently.